# Admin Sdk Next Page Token expiry time

Tags: google-app-engine, google-admin-sdk

I am using Admin SDK. I am retrieving 30 users per request. I am using `nextPageToken` to get next 30 users. Can anyone tell me how long is the `nextPageToken`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nextPageToken` doesn't have validity timeout. It's just pointer to specific location in the index.

Comment: if i take nextpagetoken value, saveed into database and after some time if i give second request call with nextPageToken then will it return next 30 users.?

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned in my answer this is just a pointer to the position in the index. Remember that something may be added or removed in the mean time, so duplicated users may be returned (user removed) or some users will be omitted (a new users added).